# Darlington configuration using BJTs

Tags: bjt, darlington, power-dissipation

Does a Darlington configuration using two BJTs, say a BC548, override the total power they could dissipate?

Comment: What do you mean with "override"? That makes no sense - the thermal power limit is a per-device property, so no matter how you use these devices you need to make sure every individual one doesn't overheat. Electronics involves 0 magic!

Comment: The end transistor in darl. pair determines the max. power dissipation.

Answer (score 1):

No. The power a transistor can dissipate is intrinsic to the transistor, not the wiring or topology (Darlington pair, in your case). You can't override specified power limits by changing the configuration. You can, however, get higher power by using multiple transistors at the same time to share the load. But each transistor will still be limited by it's specifications (see "Absolute Maximum Ratings" in the respective datasheets).

Answer (score 1):

No.

In a standard Darlington configuration, there is a connection to only one of the two emitters.  Therefore, 100% of all of the circuit current goes through that one transistor.  Some of it gets there by going through the other transistor, but that does not change the total power dissipation.

AND - because one of the transistors cannot saturate, the power dissipation in a saturated-switch application can actually be greater than of a single transistor.